# Spring + Angular JS for File upload with other form fields value

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am new to Angular JS. I am doing file upload with other fields value in single request . I tried without file upload. I got request in server and persisted. my server side DTO Object class is TopicDTO. I have added file html element then tried, I am not able to receive the request in server. I have changed the request header and method signatue it is not working.

My need is, upload file with some other fields value in server. My request should map with TopicDTO. where I have change my code.

Spring + Angular JS

JS

```
app.controller('topicAddCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.topicname = "Success";
    $scope.topicdesc = "Desc";
    $scope.topicdate = "";
    $scope.file = null;
    $scope.prereq = "HTML,JS";
    $scope.seats = 10;
    $scope.pid = 1;
    $scope.pname = "Author";
    $scope.pemail = "Author@gmail.com";


    $scope.setDeck = function(fileInput) {

        $scope.file=fileInput.value;
        console.log(" File configured............"+$scope.file);
    };
    $scope.register=function (){

        var dataObj = {
                topicName : $scope.topicname,
                topicDesc : $scope.topicdesc,
                topicDate : $scope.topicdate,
                file : $scope.file,
                prereq: $scope.prereq,
                seats : $scope.seats,
                presenterId: $scope.pid,
                presenterName : $scope.pname,
                presenterEmail : $scope.pemail


        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/workshop/topic_add.do',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
            data: dataObj,
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                return data; // do nothing! FormData is very good!
            }
        }).success(function(data, status) {
        }).error(function(data, status) {
        });
    }
```

**Html**

```
<div id="topic_container" ng-app="topicAddApp"
        ng-controller="topicAddCtrl" align="center">
        <form  class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="register()">
        <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"
            style="width: 500px;" class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Topic Name</td>
                    <td><input name="topicname" ng-model="topicname" type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Topic Description</td>
                    <td><textarea cols="15" name="topicdesc" ng-model="topicdesc" class="form-control"
                            rows="2" ></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Topic Date</td>
                    <td><input name="topicdate" ng-model="topicdate" type="text" id="topicdate" class="form-control" datepicker/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Topic Deck</td>
                    <td><input name="topicdeck" ng-model="file" type="file" class="form-control"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setDeck(this)"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Pre Requesites</td>
                    <td><textarea cols="19" name="prereq" ng-model="prereq" class="form-control"
                            rows="3" ></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Seats</td>
                    <td><input name="seats" ng-model="seats" type="number" class="form-control"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Presenter Id</td>
                    <td><input name="pid" ng-model="pid" type="number" class="form-control"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Presenter Name</td>
                    <td><input name="pname" ng-model="pname" type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">Presenter Email Address</td>
                    <td><input name="pemail" ng-model="pemail" type="email" class="form-control"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input name="register" type="submit"
                        value="Register"  class="btn btn-primary"/></td>
                    <td align="center"><input name="clear" type="button"
                        value="Clear" ng-click="clear()" class="btn btn-primary"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Server Code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "topic_add.do",headers = "'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addTopic(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) {
            System.out.println(" I got the Request "+file);
}
```

**DTO Class**

```
public class TopicDTO extends BaseDTO{

    private String topicName;
    private String topicDesc;
    private String topicDate;
    private String file;

    private String prereq;
    private int presenterId;
    private String presenterName;
    private String presenterEmail;
    private int seats;

    public String getTopicName() {
        return topicName;
    }
    public void setTopicName(String topicName) {
        this.topicName = topicName;
    }
    public String getTopicDesc() {
        return topicDesc;
    }
    public void setTopicDesc(String topicDesc) {
        this.topicDesc = topicDesc;
    }
    public String getTopicDate() {
        return topicDate;
    }
    public void setTopicDate(String topicDate) {
        this.topicDate = topicDate;
    }

    public String getPrereq() {
        return prereq;
    }
    public void setPrereq(String prereq) {
        this.prereq = prereq;
    }
    public int getPresenterId() {
        return presenterId;
    }
    public void setPresenterId(int presenterId) {
        this.presenterId = presenterId;
    }
    public String getPresenterName() {
        return presenterName;
    }
    public void setPresenterName(String presenterName) {
        this.presenterName = presenterName;
    }
    public String getPresenterEmail() {
        return presenterEmail;
    }
    public void setPresenterEmail(String presenterEmail) {
        this.presenterEmail = presenterEmail;
    }
    public int getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }
    public void setSeats(int seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }
    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TopicDTO [topicName=" + topicName + ", topicDesc=" + topicDesc
                + ", topicDate=" + topicDate + ", topicDeck=" + topicDeck
                + ", prereq=" + prereq + ", presenterId=" + presenterId
                + ", presenterName=" + presenterName + ", presenterEmail="
                + presenterEmail + ", seats=" + seats + "]";
    }


}
```

**Server Code for Without file Upload**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "topic_add.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody TopicDTO topicDTO, HttpServletResponse response) {
                System.out.println(" I got the Request ");
    }
```

It was working for without fileupload. it is not working for file upload.

what changes I have to do it server side and client to make this work ?

Comment: What do you mean *It was working for without fileupload. it is not working for file upload* ?

Answer (score 0):

Your name for the file field is wrong. Change this:

```
public void addTopic(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response)
```

TO:

```
public void addTopic(@RequestParam("topicdeck") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Comment: Not working the code even after code change as per youor suggession

Comment: It will be helpful for me if I get any sample code for Spring + Angular JS file upload with form values